# how can i stop the block method DatagramSocket.receive() in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i create a `DatagramSocket` in the main thread,and then create a inner class thread to listen the port. when i close the `DatagramSocket` in the main thread, it always came across an error `socket closed` because in the inner class thread i called the `receive()` method,and it blocked the inner class thread. here is the code of the inner class:

```
class ReceiveText extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            try {
                udpSocket.receive(dp);//blocked here
                byte[] data = dp.getData();
                String message = new String(data, 0 , dp.getLength());
                setTxtAreaShowMessage(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to stop the inner class thread before close the DatagramSocket, but the `stop()` method is not recommended. how can i do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Close the socket, which will stop the receive() call from blocking.  If you first set a closed flag then in the catch (IOException) block you can safely ignore the exception if the flag is set.  (You could probably also use isClosed() method on DatagramSocket instead of a flag)

Comment: I can also confirm this works!  Nice way to break out of a worker thread which is in a receive loop on a datagram socket.

Answer (score 4):

Socket.close() does the trick. Or you can use socket.setSoTimeout(1000); the setSoTimeout() method allows you to define a timeout period in milliseconds. For example:

```
//if the socket does not receive anything in 1 second, 
//it will timeout and throw a SocketTimeoutException
//you can catch the exception if you need to log, or you can ignore it
socket.setSoTimeout(1000); 
socket.receive();
```

Here is the [javadoc for setSoTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int));

By default, the timeout is 0 which is indefinite, by changing it to a positive number, it will only block for the amount you specified. (Make sure you set it before calling socket.receive())

Here is an example answered on this site:
[set timeout for socket receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055913/set-timeout-for-socket-receive)

Answer (score 1):

With UDP, you could send the socket a datagram from another thread, so unblocking the read().  The datagran could, (depending on your protocol), contain a 'suicide' command or you could use an additional 'shutdown' boolean that the thread reads after read() returns.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

```
    while(udpSocket!=null && !udpSocket.isClosed())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            udpSocket.receive(dp);//blocked here
            byte[] data = dp.getData();
            String message = new String(data, 0 , dp.getLength());
            setTxtAreaShowMessage(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then to end the socket perform

```
    socket.close();
    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(1);
    } catch (SocketException e) {}
    socket.disconnect();
    socket = null;
```

Comment: Not clear why to check udpSocket.isClosed(): the exception can still occur and needs to be treated