# Interrupt a thread while is on socket.receive(packet); throws an error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application that runs a service with this thread:

```
public class UDPServerThread extends Thread
{
    [ ... ]

    public void run()
    {
        while (!end)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[MESSAGE_SIZE];

                // Wait an incoming message.
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                // TODO: Notify Service with packet received
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = packet;
                mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopServer()
    {
        Log.v("UDPServerThread", "stopServer");
        if (socket != null)
            socket.close();
        end = true;
    }
}
```

When I call `stopServer()` method from service I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Interrupted system call
```

Which is the right way to stop this thread while it is on `socket.receive(packet);`?

Comment: if it is socket.receive that is throwing that exception, I guess that is a normal behavior, as you're actually interrupt the call by closing the socket.

Comment: Thanks. So, I don't need to worry about, isn't it?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962121/how-can-i-stop-the-block-method-datagramsocket-receive-in-a-thread

Comment: also after setting end to true, you might want to wait until your thread actually finishes. (this has nothing to do with your question, just a tip ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real problem with this exception is that you cannot easily distinguish it from an actual I/O error.  I'd suggest switching to using a SocketChannel rather than a Socket -- then you can interrupt your server thread and it will throw a ClosedByInterruptException instead, which you can catch and handle specifically.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [javadoc of the close method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29):

> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException.

So when you call `close`, `socket.receive(packet);`, if it is currently in blocking mode, will throw a `SocketException` which is caught in your `catch (IOException e)` block and the stacktrace is printed.

Comment: Thanks. So, I don't need to worry about, isn't it?

Comment: It is the normal behaviour: when you close a socket, it stops doing what it was doing and lets you know about it. You can then decide to ignore that Exception because you closed the socket on purpose. But you might want to run some sort of checks as it might have been closed for other reasons, e.g. the connection has been lost.