# Wireless Data transfer between Google Glass and computer

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm looking for a wireless way to send data between my computer and Google Glass that doesn't involve any cloud API (GDK instead of Mirror API). I'm thinking Bluetooth. Does anyone have a preferred method for this kind of data transfer or have done something similar to this?

I also saw the post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device) from a couple months ago. Theoretically, is it be possible to modify the code so that the data transfer can be between Google glass and computer (instead of Android device)?

Comment: your question is too broad, try narrowing it down. Also you should provide some codeing attempts.

Comment: Sorry, what I am asking is that has anyone had any experience writing a GDK app to transfer images and texts from computer to the Glass via Bluetooth or theoretically, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success sending data from my computer to the Glass using simple sockets.  In my case I have some data being sent via UDP broadcast and the Glass is able to receive it and display it successfully.  Here are some links which may help.

[Receiving UDP on Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083623/receive-udp-data-on-google-glass-with-gdk)

[Need to request INTERNET permission in app manifest to create sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application)

[Interrupting a blocked UDP listen socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309976/need-an-interruptable-way-to-listen-for-udp-packets-in-a-worker-thread)

Comment: Were you able to get images sent via UDP, or just texts?

Comment: In my case the UDP packets did not contain images.  I suppose you could send images over UDP but keep in mind there's a max size on UDP packets (I've seen indications of this being 65k and also ~500 bytes, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet) for a discussion on that).  Having said that, if you want to send images you might be better off using TCP.  But TCP should work just as well as UDP on Glass using the links I sent above (you just need to make TCP socket calls instead of UDP).