# Thread interrupt() not interrupting the thread in java (UDP Socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

This question has been asked before here.I tried to figure out the problem by learning from them but still I can't find the solution to it.I am posting a minimal code with the interrupt problem.I am probably missing something very silly which you guys might be able to help with.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Optitrack implements Runnable {
private MulticastSocket s;

public Optitrack(MulticastSocket socket) {
    // SOcket acquired from parent
    this.s = socket;
}

public void start_track() {
    InetAddress group;
    try {
        group = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xx.xx.xx");
        s = new MulticastSocket(1511);
        s.joinGroup(group);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Have we joined the multicast group?");
    while (true) {

        // get their responses!
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
        DatagramPacket recv = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        try {
            s.receive(recv);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Some calculations and functions here which are not important to
        // the problem
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    start_track();
}

}
```

Also here is the code snippet where I call the interrupt from the parent thread.

```
if(track.isAlive())
                {
                    //if(socket!=null)
                    //{
                        socket.close();
                    //}
                    track.interrupt();
                    //track.stop();
                }
```

track is initialised as

```
tracker=new Optitrack(socket);
track=new Thread(tracker);
track.start();
```

I am basically just trying to close the socket to interrupt the receive function and then interrupt the thread itself.I previously tried without interrupting the receive function and directly calling Thread.interrupt with the above code but with same results.

It would be of great help if someone can figure out what's wrong or what the correct way to do this is.

Comment: Can you tell what is "track" and where have you initialized it ?

Comment: I don't know your complete scenario, but this could help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--

Answer (score 1):

If you interrupt a thread, you have to check in the thread and perform exiting logic by yourself - interrupting does no "black magic" like canceling the interrupted thread.

Interrupting a blocking reading on a socket is mostly done by simply closing the socket combined with a try-catch-block spanning the reading and reacting to a closed socket by exiting orderly.

Comment: I do check if the thread is interrupted inside the while loop and try to exit the thread.I would suppose on closing the socket, it should perform a loop, check the interrupted status and exit there.Or am I missing something.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the point of "This method blocks until a datagram is received" (http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket) which basically means that your check on interrupted is executed once and then the call blocks and won't exit until something is received.

Comment: but why doesn't closing the socket from the main thread doesn't unblock the receive.

Comment: Perhaps this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962121/how-can-i-stop-the-block-method-datagramsocket-receive-in-a-thread